# How to Quickly save/load 200,000 of double type into memory using iOS?

Tags: ios, memory, game-engine, numeric

I tried to use NSKeyedArchiver to save/load numerical data which has 200,000 of doubles. It took around 160 secs to save, and 1900 secs to load.

When I changed to use Core Data, it is even slower.

I couldn't find un-keyed archiver in iOS however. The code is like below:

```
VectorWeights::iterator wit;

for ( wit=m_Weights.begin(),ind=0; wit<m_Weights.end(); wit++,ind++ )
{
    [archiver encodeObject:[[NNW alloc] initWithNNWeight:*wit] forKey:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@_W%ld",label,ind]];
}
```

NNW has encoder as below:

```
@implementation NNW
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:self.internal->label forKey:NNWid];
    [coder encodeDouble:self.internal->value forKey:NNWvalue];
}
```

Is there any better way to do so?

Update: label is of type NString* and VectorWeight is std::vector

Comment: What's the type of `VectorWeights`? is that all you wish to save? What's the type of the label?

Comment: its probably worth to use sqlite to save / load such amount of records. Check FMDB (https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) open source library.

Comment: Label is Nstring* which is the name of node. VectorWeight is std::vector of Weight which has label and value to save/load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create an NSMutableData object, make it big enough (200000 * sizeof (double)), get a pointer to the bytes, memcpy the 200000 doubles into it, and save it to a file. Should take significantly less than 100ms.

Or just

```
double* p = malloc (200000 * sizeof (double));
... fill with 200,000 double values
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:p length: 200000 * sizeof (double)];
[data writeToURL:someURL atomically:YES];
```

Comment: But how about the NString* label that associated with each node? Is there any way to join two NSData of different types in sequence into one (something like NSunkeyedArchiver) ?

Comment: This solution is pretty fast. The labels are not that critical and not part of the question any way. Thank you